# Accessing MediaWiki extensions

Tags: php, linux, mediawiki, lamp, mediawiki-extensions

Currently I am working with MediaWiki. I followed the tutorial `https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-mediawiki-on-ubuntu-14-04` and successfully installed it on my Ubuntu 14.04 system. When I restarted the Apace server, everything worked and I could see the Main page perfectly.

Now I am trying to use the WikiEditor extension. It's already installed in `/var/www/html/extensions` folder. I have also modified `LocalSettings.php` file in `/var/www/html/` folder and appended the following line.

```
require_once "$IP/extensions/WikiEditor/WikiEditor.php";
```

When I browse to `localhost/index.php/Special:Version`, I can see WikiEditor listed there. But when I go to `localhost/index.php/Special:WikiEditor`, it says "No Such Page".

So I would like to know the complete url to access a MediaWiki extension.

Answer (score 0):

This extension does not have a Special page, so you can't "access" it.

What that extension does is provide a toolbar for better user experience when editing a page. When you create/edit a page you will see something like the image bellow. 
[image]

Maybe you have to clear your browser cache and reload the page first.

If what you want is to customize (add buttons, etc), you might take a look at [this page](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:WikiEditor/Toolbar_customization/Library).

Comment: Thank you for the answer..But let's say I add an extension called test to `/var/www/html/extensions` and appended the line `require_once "$IP/extensions/test/test.php";` to LocalSettings.php. What should be the url to access it?

Comment: It depends on what the extension does. An extension can have multiple special pages, or no special page at all, or the page name can be different from the extension name. For example [voteNY extension](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:VoteNY) implements `Special:TopRatings` instead of `Special:VoteNY`. The documentation on each extension usually let you know the functionality provided.

Answer (score 0):

Extensions are not special pages,

Extensions declare special pages through 1) classes extending SpecialPage 2) declaration of these classes into $wgSpecialPages array.

See BlogPage extension for example.